# Start template animation as soon as control is loaded

Tags: wpf, templates, animation, storyboard

I have the following code inside my `ControlTemplate`:

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ControlTemplate.Loaded">
            <EventTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
```

And I want to start Storyboard which I have defined in ControlTemplate, when control is loaded. So my question is: what in ControlTemplate rises Loaded event?

I can't use FrameworkElement.Loaded as object which are target of my animation aren't accessible when the Loaded event is fired.

P.S. `ControlTemplate.Loaded` not working

Answer (score 2):

The `ControlTemplate` class has no `Loaded` event. Try just using `Loaded` or `XXX.Loaded` where `XXX` is the name of the type of control that you are templating, not the `ControlTemplate`.